# Manipulacao de arquivo txt no JAVA

Tags: java, string, txt, append

Ola ,sou iniciante no java e preciso criar um programa que crie um arquivo txt com um conteudo pre definido , leia ele e divida o conteudo desse arquivo em dois arquivos txt diferentes , sendo o conteudo passado pro primeiro arquivo todas as linhas que comecem com // (comentarios do java) e passe o restante (sera um codigo de java) para o segundo arquivo e por fim compile esse codigo.

A maior parte do programa eu consigo fazer, mas a minha duvida esta na parte em que eu preciso passar o conteudo para um arquivo diferente.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //conteudo
    String conteudo = "arquivo inicial\nlinha2"; //conteudo inicial
    String conteudo1 = null; //o que vai ser separado para o arquivo1(comentarios)
    String conteudo2 = null; //o que vai ser separado para o arquivo2(codigo a ser compilado)

    //cria os 3 arquivos (inicial , txt dos comentarios e txt do codigo
    File arquivo = new File("arquivo.txt");
    File arquivo1 = new File ("arquivo1.txt");
    File arquivo2 = new File("arquivo2.txt");

    //prepara pra escrever no arquivo inicial 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    //escreve e fecha o arquivo
    bw.write(conteudo);
    bw.close();

    //le o arquivo linha por linha
    FileReader ler = new FileReader("arquivo.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(ler);
    String linha;
    while( (linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(linha);  //printa linha por linha do arquivo inicial
        if (linha.contains("//")) {    //se o arquivo conter // , ele separa para outro arquivo
            }
        else {

        }
    }

    }
```

Minhas duvidas sao: o if que vera se a linha contem duas barras(no caso o comentario em java) devera ficar dentro ou fora do while que le o arquivo ate nao existir mais nada para ler , e qual comando eu posso usar dentro do if que seja capaz de separar apenas as linhas com comentarios e crie uma nova string com ela?

Muito obrigado a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completei seu código com uma implementação bem simples.
Recomendo utilizar as novas APIs(Classes) de Arquivos do Java 7 para manipulação de arquivos, já que elas possuem alguns métodos que abstraem a escrita e leitura de arquivos de seu código.

Implementação:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Conteudo inicial.
        String conteudo = "Linha Codigo\n//Comentario"; //conteudo inicial

        //Obtem um path para cada um dos 3 arquivos (inicial ,comentarios e txt do codigo
        Path arquivoInicial = Paths.get("arquivoInicial.txt");
        Path arquivoComentarios = Paths.get("arquivoComentarios.txt");
        Path arquivoCodigo = Paths.get("arquivoCodigo.txt");

        //Escreve o conteudo inicial
        Files.write(arquivoInicial, conteudo.getBytes());

        //Chama a funcao de fitro, pasando o arquivo Origem e os arquivos de destino.
        filtrarComentarios(arquivoInicial, arquivoComentarios, arquivoCodigo);
    }

    /**
     * Filtra o codigo de um arquivo, separando em código e comentarios.
     */
    public static void filtrarComentarios(Path arquivoInicial, Path arquivoComentarios, Path arquivoCodigo) throws IOException {
        //Cria duas listas para armazenar o codigo e comentarios.
        List<String> comentarios = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> codigo = new ArrayList<>();

        //Itera todas as linhas do arquivoInicial, o método readAllLines de Files retorna uma Lista
        //de String que denota as linhas do arquivo.
        for (String linha : Files.readAllLines(arquivoInicial, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            //Utiliza o método trim() para que qualquer comentario seja detectado, o método trim() remove todo whitespace(espaco, tabs) do inicio e fim da String.
            if (linha.trim().startsWith("//")) {
                comentarios.add(linha);
            } else {
                codigo.add(linha);
            }
        }

        //Escreve o resultado em cada arquivo.
        Files.write(arquivoComentarios, comentarios);
        Files.write(arquivoCodigo, codigo);
    }
}
```

A ideia do código é iterar sobre todas as linhas do arquivos e filtrar as linhas cujo caracteres inicias sejam `//`, após iteração o resultado é escrito nos dois arquivos.

É importante notar que os métodos utilizados da classe `Files` lançam a exceção IOException caso ocorra um erro durante a escrita/leitura de um arquivo, assim interrompendo a execução, é recomendado que este erro seja tratado com um bloco try/catch porém não foi feito para simplificar a implementação.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, e eu já estava pensando em colocar em um bloco try/catch para tratar as excecoes , mas por se tratar de uma dúvida pessoal preferi deixar assim para economizar tempo, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.